# function definition, $ symbol apparition after variables

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, functions, variable-definitions

I have a proble with a system of two differential equations

```
operh[h_, c_] :=  h D[D[h, r, r] + 1/r D[h, r] - h, r] + m D[c, r]
operc[h_, c_] := {cmt h + 1/Sqrt[R² - r²] -    1/r D[r h (1 + h⁴  D[c, r]²) D[c, r], r]}
```

I want to solve the case when they are equal to zero

```
deqh := operh[h[r], c[r]] == 0
deqc := operc [h[r], c[r]] == 0
```

For that I define "shot", a function of "cmt" (appears in the second equation), and of one coefficient "coefh" (appears in the taylor expansion of h) as follow:

```
shot[coefh_? NumericQ, cmt_? NumericQ] := {taylor expansion of h (variable r), taylor expansion of c (variable r); NDSolve{deqh,deqc}}
```

My problem is when I try to evaluate my fonction "shot", (I have an error message of course) and variables followed by the dollar symbol appear:

```
in[]:shot[0.1,0.1]
error:divided by 0, + other error messages
out[]:2.85328 (2 - r$)+ higher terms in r$, rh[r]c'[r]+ other terms with normal r
```

Where does this $ come from ? I beleive some of the other errors messages are related to this one.

Sorry for the big code post, but this is my very first use of mathematica and I didn't manage to isolate the error better than that...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please post a complete working example (without the pseudo code "taylor expansion" in the third box).  Look at `Series` if you don't know about it.

Answer (score 4):

The `$` is a symbol used by Mathematica to generate local variable names for variables that are confined to a particular scope.  For instance, if you run

```
Module[{x}, Print[x]]
```

you'll find it prints something like `x$4456`.  This is the name Mathematica gave the variable to distinguish it from any other `x`'s outside the `Module`.